# Test-First Ruby Hello Lab

Tags: ruby, rspec

Alex Chaffee's test-first ruby lessons teach how to use rspec. I'm currently stuck on the first exercise of it, `00_hello`. I followed the directions and created a file `hello.rb` which contains the code:

```
def hello
   "Hello!"
end
```

and placed it in a directory `00_hello` with `hello_specs.rb`. When I type `rake` in the terminal from the directory `00_hello`, I get the following errors, which aren't like rspec errors:

```
(in /Users/stevenjli/Documents/App Academy/learn_ruby-master)
/Users/stevenjli/Documents/App Academy/learn_ruby-master/00_hello/hello_spec.rb:116:in `require':     cannot load such file -- hello (LoadError)
from /Users/stevenjli/Documents/App Academy/learn_ruby-master/00_hello/hello_spec.rb:116:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:in `load'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:in `block in load_spec_files'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:in `each'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:in `load_spec_files'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
rake aborted!

/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/ruby -S rspec /Users/stevenjli/Documents/App\         
Academy/learn_ruby-master/00_hello/hello_spec.rb -I/Users/stevenjli/Documents/App   
Academy/learn_ruby-master/00_hello -I/Users/stevenjli/Documents/App Academy/learn_ruby-master 
/00_hello/solution -f documentation -r ./rspec_config failed
```

I'm guessing there's something wrong with my setup. Here are the versions I'm using.

- Mac OS 10.8.2
- Ruby version 1.9.3
- rake 0.9.2.2
- rspec version 2.12.2

Comment: `.` is not in LOAD_PATH by default.

Answer (score 2):

Check your directory structure for 00_hello folder. It should be like this

```
 ├── hello.rb
 ├── hello_spec.rb
 └── index.html
```

`Rakefile` given by `learn_ruby` takes care of adding correct directories to load path so you don't have to worry about it, unless you have changed it somewhere without understanding.

If you still have problem, post your `Rakefile` here

Comment: Thanks everyone for responding.  I eventually fixed it by replacing "require" with "require_relative" and calling with rspec instead of rake.

Answer (score 2):

If it helps anyone, I had the exact same issue on ruby 1.9.3.  My solution was three-fold:

1. Run `gem install rspec; bundle update; bundle install`
2. CD into 00_hello, then edit the `require` line to read `require './hello'`
3. Run `rspec hello_spec.rb`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running rake from the root directory of the test-first lessons?

Also halfelf might be right, maybe they have been running ruby 1.8 which includes `.` into the $LOAD_PATH and you are running 1.9.3 which doesn't do this, since it is not necessary with `require_relative` etc.

Comment: Thanks for responding Phil, when I run from rake from the root directory, I get the error: `No examples matching /Users/stevenjli/Documents/App Academy/learn_ruby-master/*_spec.rb could be found`

I also used require "{actual path to file}", I get the error `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:in load': cannot load such file -- /Users/stevenjli/Documents/App Academy/learn_ruby-master/Academy/learn_ruby-master/00_hello (LoadError)`

Comment: You can't run `rake` from root directory of test-first lessons because in the `Rakefile` it is using `task.pattern = "#{lab}/*_spec.rb"` pattern where `lab` is a particular folder for a lesson. eg. `00_hello`

Comment: His output suggests that rake is looking for `*_spec.rb` in the root of `learn_ruby-master`? Also the require seems wrong, he tries to require `00_hello` in the root directory.